# Parabolic bundle and chern class

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I'm a physicist and I'm trying to figure out some things about parabolic bundles.
In particular I'd like to understand which is the relationship, if present, between the parabolic degree and the first chern class of the bundle.
A rigorous definition of the degree of a bundle will be appreciated too.
Thanks

Comment: Is this over a curve, or a polarized variety?

Comment: Is over a curve

Comment: The usual degree and the first Chern class are defined for vector bundles (not parabolic). If your bundle has a parabolic structure, you get the parabolic degree by adding a correction term defined in terms of the parabolic structure. What is the problem?

Comment: I think I didn't explain well. So, my problem is if there is a way to define the Chern class of a parabolic vector bundle in terms of its parabolic degree

Comment: What is the Chern class of a parabolic bundle?

Comment: Probably I miss too many things and I'm asking a stupid question, sorry. Anyway I thought that the definition of first Chern class for a vector bundle was applicable in presence of a parabolic structure too and I was wondering if there is a relation with the parabolic degree. I guess that the question: is there any relation between the degree of a vector bundle and his first Chern class? is in some sense equivalent. thanks

Comment: I'm not really sure why the reaction to this question is so negative. My guess is that the parabolic degree *ought to be* expressible as Chern-Weil integral for a suitably chosen metric on the restriction of the bundle to the open part. Some results along these lines can be found in papers of Biquard or T. Mochizuki.

Comment: (If you're willing to work with stacks) If your parabolic bundles have rational weights, then they come from some vector bundle on a root stack over your curve, and you can take the first Chern class there. Then by taking a degree on the stack you get back the parabolic degree.
For some details see for example "Fibrés paraboliques et champ des racines" by Niels Borne, http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~borne/Recherche/ParRac.pdf